# How to fix 'java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space'

Tags: java

im making a java .jar application, which contains graphic content mostly are images at full hd. Currently there's around 70 mb of weight. Most of images uploading during scene change. But sometimes, when im trying to download 2-3 mb image, or .gif, im getting 'java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.'

I know about possible solution via -xmx and -xms, but it's a bad solution, how should i work with images/imageview ports, to prevent this error?

Could initialize of all images into the css stylesheets instead of local functions help?

There's an example of current initialization in function.

```
public void Inventory(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, x, y, Color.LIGHTBLUE);
    primaryStage.sceneProperty();
    scene.getStylesheets().add("images/style.css");

    Image Inventory = new Image("images/Inventory.jpg");
    ImageView InventoryView = new ImageView(Inventory);
    InventoryView.setFitHeight(y); InventoryView.setFitWidth(x);

    Image WeaponUnpressed = new Image("images/Buttons/Weapons_Unpressed.png");
    ImageView WeaponUnpressedView = new ImageView(WeaponUnpressed);
    Image WeaponPressed = new Image("images/Buttons/Weapons_Pressed.png");
    ImageView WeaponPressedView = new ImageView(WeaponPressed);
    Image WeaponHighlighted = new Image("images/Buttons/Weapons_Highlighted.png");
    ImageView WeaponHighlightedView = new ImageView(WeaponHighlighted);}
```

Most of images initializing this way.

Full error message :

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.lang.Object.clone(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.iio.gif.GIFImageLoader2.decodePalette(GIFImageLoader2.java:323)
        at com.sun.javafx.iio.gif.GIFImageLoader2.load(GIFImageLoader2.java:234)
        at com.sun.javafx.iio.ImageStorage.loadAll(ImageStorage.java:364)
        at com.sun.javafx.iio.ImageStorage.loadAll(ImageStorage.java:324)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PrismImageLoader2.loadAll(PrismImageLoader2.java:127)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PrismImageLoader2.<init>(PrismImageLoader2.java:71)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.loadImage(QuantumToolkit.java:727)
        at javafx.scene.image.Image.loadImage(Image.java:1065)
        at javafx.scene.image.Image.initialize(Image.java:807)
        at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:621)
        at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager.getCachedImage(StyleManager.java:765)
        at javafx.scene.image.ImageView$2.invalidated(ImageView.java:257)
        at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:109)
        at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:144)
        at javafx.css.StyleableStringProperty.set(StyleableStringProperty.java:83)
        at javafx.css.StyleableStringProperty.applyStyle(StyleableStringProperty.java:69)
        at javafx.css.StyleableStringProperty.applyStyle(StyleableStringProperty.java:45)
        at javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper.transitionToState(CssStyleHelper.java:774)
        at javafx.scene.Node.impl_processCSS(Node.java:9189)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1280)
        at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9056)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.doCSSPass(Scene.java:545)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.preferredSize(Scene.java:1643)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_preferredSize(Scene.java:1720)
        at javafx.stage.Window$SceneModel.invalidated(Window.java:592)
        at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:111)
        at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
        at javafx.stage.Window.setScene(Window.java:548)
        at javafx.stage.Stage.setScene(Stage.java:252)
        at sample.Main.WorldMap(Main.java:7753)
        at sample.Main$399.handle(Main.java:6512)
```

Comment: when you say `2-3 mb image`, you means 2-3mb per images? How many are there?

Comment: Note that you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: method names and variable names are written in camelCase.

Comment: summary there's around 70 mb of images. completely different.

Comment: @MCEmperor sorry for it.

Comment: When you talk about image size do you mean size on disk or the expanded size in RAM? This can make a significant difference.

Comment: Try using [image constructors which specify height and width](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.InputStream,double,double,boolean,boolean)) for the images, that way the system does not necessarily need to store the full-size uncompressed image in memory.